# Running shell script from php file cannot create / write / remove files outside of CWD

Tags: php, apache, shell, file-permissions, shell-exec

The functionality works fine when I want to create / write / files within the 
PHP script's current working directory ... but trying to use absolute paths to create / write / remove files outside of the CWD does not work.

**Shell Script** - Located in */home/tt4mc/scripts/*

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "logging" > /home/tt4mc/scripts/log.log
touch /home/tt4mc/scripts/test.log
```

**PHP File** - *LOCATED in /home/tt4mc/admin/*

```php
<?php

shell_exec("/home/tt4mc/scripts/script.sh");
```

The above does not work ... both files are 0775 permissions localuser:apache
... please note that all other operations in the shell script do work when run from the PHP file ... I am thinking it must have to do with file permissions because they only operations that do not work are having to do with creating / writing / removing files.

NOTE: I am running the PHP script as apache user.

**EDIT**

As @msg noted in the comment below, it's important to know that these scripts are in different directories and the actions will be executed in the PHP script's current working directory ... these files will be created / written to / removed in that cwd ... but i cannot get it to work in any other directory.

Comment: @msg The shell script uses absolute paths as well as the php script i will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: A few hints: You don't run anything from the browser, but (probably) from Apache. That may also make the difference. Also, please replace the "linux" tag with "apache". In general, read the description of tags first and don't blindly apply them even if SO suggests that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/home/tt4mc/admin/ has localuser:apache 0775 permissions

/home/tt4mc/scripts/ has localuser:localuser 0775 permissions

When running the php script from the browser it is executing as apache user ... threfore it cannot write.